# What's the best replacement for timeGetTime to avoid wrap-around?

Tags: c++, windows, time

[timeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757629(VS.85).aspx) seems to be quite good to query for system time. However, its return value is 32-bit only, so it wraps around every 49 days approx.

It's not too hard to detect the rollover in calling code, but it adds some complexity, and (worse) requires keeping a state.

Is there some replacement for [timeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757629(VS.85).aspx) that would not have this wrap-around problem (probably by returning a 64-bit value), and have roughly the same precision and cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, tracking roll-over requires state.  It can be as simple as just incrementing your own 64-bit counter on each callback.

It is pretty unusual to want to track time periods to a resolution as low as 1 millisecond for up to 49 days.  You'd have to worry that the accuracy is still there after such a long period.  The next step is to use the clock, GetTickCount(64), GetSystemTimeAsFileTime have a resolution of 15.625 milliseconds and are kept accurate with a time server.

Comment: The count toward rollover starts when the system starts, so the program does not have to be running for 49 days to see a rollover.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you need to time an event that is over 49 days, **you can SAFELY ignore the wrap-around**.  Just always subtract the previous timeGetTime() from the current timeGetTime() and you will *always* obtain a delta measured time that is accurate, even across wrap-around -- *provided that you are timing events whose total duration is under 49 days*.  This all works due to how unsigned modular math works inside the computer.

```
// this code ALWAYS works, even with wrap-around!
DWORD dwStart = timeGetTime();
// provided the event timed here has a duration of less than 49 days
DWORD dwDuration = timeGetTime()-dwStart;
```

TIP: look into TimeBeginPeriod(1L) to increase the accuracy of timeGetTime().

BUT... if you want a 64-bit version of timeGetTime, here it is:

```
__int64 timeGetTime64() {
    static __int64 time64=0;
    // warning: if multiple threads call this function, protect with a critical section!
    return (time64 += (timeGetTime()-(DWORD)time64));
    }
```

Please note that if this function is not called at least once every 49 days, that this function will fail to properly detect a wrap-around.

Comment: May I suggest adding `__declspec(thread)` to your definition of `time64`, as a more efficient solution than a critical section?

Answer (score 5):

What platform?

You could use [GetTickCount64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411(VS.85).aspx) if you're running on Vista or later, or synthesise your own `GetTickCount64()` from `GetTickCount()` and a timer...

I deal with the rollover issue in `GetTickCount()` and synthesising a `GetTickCount64()` on platforms that don't support it here on my blog about testing non-trivial code:  http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2008/04/practical-testing-17---a-whole-new-approach.html

Comment: FWIW, `GetTickCount` and `timeGetTime` are [not interchangeable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2009/09/02/whats-the-difference-between-gettickcount-and-timegettime/). They both have millisecond _resolution_, but GetTickCount only has 10–16 ms _precision_, whereas `timeGetTime` typically has 1–5 ms _precision_.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397%28VS.85%29.aspx). It fills a `FILETIME` struct that contains a "64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)"

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to use it?  I frequently use the Win32 equivalent when checking for durations that I know will be under 49 days.  For example the following code will always work.

```
DWORD start = timeGetTime();
DoSomthingThatTakesLessThen49Days();
DWORD duration = timeGetTime() - start;
```

Even if `timeGetTime` rolled over while calling `DoSomthingThatTakesLessThen49Days` `duration` will still be correct.

Note the following code could fail on rollover.

```
DWORD start = timeGetTime();
DoSomthingThatTakesLessThen49Days();
if (now + 5000 < timeGetTime())
{
}
```

but can easy be re-written to work as follows

```
DWORD start = timeGetTime();
DoSomthingThatTakesLessThen49Days();
if (timeGetTime() - start < 5000)
{
}
```

Comment: Thomas' comment (above) applies for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can guarantee that this function will called at least once every 49 days, something like this will work:

```
// Returns current time in milliseconds
uint64_t timeGetTime64()
{
   static uint32_t _prevVal    = 0;
   static uint64_t _wrapOffset = 0;

   uint32_t newVal = (uint32_t) timeGetTime();
   if (newVal < _prevVal) _wrapOffset += (((uint64_t)1)<<32);
   _prevVal = newVal;
   return _wrapOffset+newVal;
}
```

Note that due to the use of static variables, this function isn't multithread-safe, so if you plan on calling it from multiple threads you should serialize it via a critical section or mutex or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fully meets your needs, but

```
std::chrono::system_clock
```

might be along the lines of what you're looking for.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock

Comment: More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783468/is-there-a-standard-library-equivalent-of-timegettime), but a full benchmarked comparison of capabilities of both libraries on various platforms would be a better reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RDTSC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95%28VS.80%29.aspx) intrinsic. To get time in milliseconds you could get transform coefficient:

```
double get_rdtsc_coeff() {
  static double coeff = 0.0;
  if ( coeff < 1.0 ) { // count it only once
    unsigned __int64 t00 = __rdtsc();
    Sleep(1000);
    unsigned __int64 t01 = __rdtsc();
    coeff = (t01-t00)/1000.0;
  }

  return coeff; // transformation coefficient
}
```

Now you could get count of milliseconds from the last reset:

```
__int64 get_ms_from_start() {
  return static_cast<__int64>(__rdtsc()/get_rdtsc_coeff());
}
```

---

If your system uses SpeedStep or similar technologies you could use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)/[QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions. Windows gives guarantees then the frequency cannot change while the system is running.

Comment: SpeedStep but an end to the usefulness of this approach.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep

Comment: True, for SpeedStep systems this will not work. Updated my answer.