# Is there any way to manipulate the value of the TimeGetTime timer

Tags: delphi, testing, windows-xp, delphi-2006, gettickcount

I have an app using the GetLastInputInfo function and compares it with the value of GetTickCount (which returns the number of milliseconds since Windows started) as a way of detecting nobody at the keyboard or mouse application for more than a certain time.  This code had a bug which did not manifest itself will the GetTickCount counter rolled over - around 49 days.

I want to be able to test applications generally for susceptibility to this roll-over - but faster than every 7 weeks.  Does anyone know of a means of forcing the value returned by GetTickCount (example in any legible programming language - including .BAT - is fine)?

This isn't really a duplicate of [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825824/whats-the-best-replacement-for-timegettime-to-avoid-wrap-around).  I'm interested in a technique that will allow me to characterise the behaviour  of code that's already in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

Run the checked build of Windows. It artificially sets the `GetTickCount` value to 1 hour before rollover at boot, so that the counter value rolls over in 1 hour instead of 49 days.

Comment: Sounds almost perfect.  I am [downloading it](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1260) now, but (assuming I install it on a virtual machine) what will happen as regards licensing when I install it?