# Is there a standard library equivalent of timeGetTime()?

Tags: c++, stl, std

I've tried search without really finding an answer to this question that meets me requirements or explains it clearly enough.

I'm looking for a function or a way to implement a function that can retrieve the number of ticks or milliseconds in the same way that the timeGetTime() function does in windows.

I'm looking for a solution that only uses standard C++, no additional libraries or platform specifics (like timeGetTime() on windows or a linux equivalent; a multi-platform solution).

I'm trying to keep my code platform independent at the lower level of the library and I just want to know if anyone can tell me/point me to the way to put something together similar to timeGetTime().

Thanks

Update: I'm not necessarily looking for high performance and accuracy, I only need millisecond precision to see how much time has elapsed since I last checked.

Comment: Why `timeGetTime()`? It doesn't have very good resolution, and it overflows after a while. Why not use `QueryPerformanceCounter` or even `GetTickCount64`? (The Linux equivalent of `QueryPerformanceCounter` is `clock_gettime`, by the way.)

Comment: I'm not too bother which, timeGetTime is just a function I am familiar with that does what I need from a windows perspective. I'm just looking for something that isn't platform specific.

Comment: The `timeGetTime` function returns the **time elapsed since Windows was started** -- Do you want exactly that, or just want to measure time intervals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ever so verbose [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library added in C++11.

It has different types of clocks depending on what you want, with `system_clock` being the only one that can be used with `time_t` and `high_resolution_clock` being the one with the smallest tick possible.

Timing things is relatively simple with it, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //do stuff here
    auto then = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(then-now).count();
}
```

Comment: this looks like a solution I could use, however, I am getting a compile exception trying to use your example involving the duration_cast. Message: no instance of function template "std::chrono::duration_cast" matches the argument list

Comment: @AdamGoss I can't seem to replicate it, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Never mind, I had changed it to now use the then-now part as I'm only interested in get the time value at a point.  Calling the time_since_epoch gets rid of the compile error. I assume this is what I am after.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 added header `<chrono>` which provides a standardized way to read the system time with higher resolution than the old `localtime`.  Accuracy varies wildly by platform, however.

The `steady_clock` class will probably be most useful to you.